# Include boxplot icon in legend with ggplot when combining boxplot with other chart type

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am including both geom_boxplot (for continuous measures) as well as geom_point (for binary measures) in a descriptive figure. Example code using the cars data set below.

I would like to include a legend which lists that the points (shape 9) reflect binary variables whereas the boxplot reflects continuous variables. In other words, I'm wondering whether I can make a legend with two elements:

[shape 9 icon] Binary Variables

[boxplot icon] Continuous Variables

```r
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- cars %>%
  mutate(dist = ifelse(dist > 10, 1, 0)) %>%
  reshape2::melt()

ggplot(data=df, aes(x = value, y = factor(variable))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = ifelse(variable == "speed", value, NA), y = variable),
               width=0.2, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(data=df %>% filter(variable == "dist"), aes(x = mean(value), y = variable),
             shape=9)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the legends, you need to ensure that your geoms have an associated scale. In this case, you probably want a shape scale and a fill scale:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = value, y = factor(variable), fill = factor(variable))) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = ifelse(variable == "speed", value, NA), y = variable),
               width = 0.2, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(data = df %>% filter(variable == "dist"), 
             aes(x = mean(value), y = variable, shape = factor(mean(value)))) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = 9, name = "dist") +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("speed", "speed"), values = c("white", "white"), 
                    na.translate = FALSE, name = "speed")
```

[image]